# how to increase performance

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am thinking about how to improve the performance of the charts made by d3 when the nodes quantity is huge.

I know using canvas could help on this issue but I just want to talk about the SVG.

Firstly, I create a huge data and initialise the SVG:

```
let arr = [];
let randomColor = function () {
    return d3.schemeCategory20[Math.floor(Math.random() * 20)];
};
let random = function (span) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * span);
};

for (let i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
    arr.push({
        index: i,
        color: randomColor(),
        x: random(400),
        y: random(300),
        width: random(50),
        height: random(50)
    });
}

let svg = d3.select("#box")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", 400)
    .attr("height", 300);
```

Then, create a function to calculate time consuming when function passed in:

```
    function getTimeSpan (func) {
        svg.html("");
        let start = new Date();
        func();
        console.log(func.name + " consume: " + (new Date() - start) + " ms.");
    }
```

After that, I create some test functions that could produce rectangles content:

```
function normalRoutine () {
    svg.selectAll("rect")
        .data(arr)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("x", d => d.x)
        .attr("y", d => d.y)
        .attr("fill", d => d.color)
        .attr("width", d => d.width)
        .attr("height", d => d.height);
}

function normalRoutineWithEach () {
    svg.selectAll("rect")
        .data(arr)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .each(function (d) { //  <- EACH iteration
            d3.select(this)
            .attr("x", d.x)
            .attr("y", d.y)
            .attr("fill", d.color)
            .attr("width", d.width)
            .attr("height", d.height);
        });
}

// underscore template: https://underscorejs.org/#template
let tpl = '<% _.each(arr, function (rect) { %>' +
            '<rect x="<%= rect.x %>" y="<%= rect.y %>" width="<%= rect.width %>" height="<%= rect.height %>" fill="<%= rect.color %>"></rect>' +
            '<% }); %>';
function stringInjection () {
    // "_.template(tpl)(arr)" return all rects in HTML string
    svg.html(_.template(tpl)(arr));
}
function stringInjectionAndDataBinding () {
    svg.html(_.template(tpl)(arr));

    // Here is the only differenc compared with "stringInjection"
    svg.selectAll("rect").data(arr);
}
```

Comparing time consuming respectively(manualy pass test function to **getTimeSpan** ):

- normalRoutine consume: **2419** ms.
- normalRoutineWithEach consume: **2460** ms.
- stringInjection consume: **1914** ms.
- stringInjectionAndDataBinding consume: **2784** ms.

Intact code reference [CodePen](https://codepen.io/1Cr18Ni9/pen/rqrGRo?editors=1010).

As you can see:

- **stringInjection** - the fastest way to render but data is not bind
- **stringInjectionAndDataBinding** - double iteration makes the function the slowest to run
- minor difference between **normalRoutine** and **normalRoutineWithEach**

Anyone can give me other ways to improve script performance.

Suggestions and comments are appriciated. Thanks for reading!

Comment: This is a rather broad question; what is your objective? Using D3 there is always a tradeoff between performance and ease-of-use. It really depends on what you are trying to achieve. On my machine executed in Chrome I get results of 1794/1866/1663/1750 ms which don't really seem worth optimizing unless you aim for some extreme applications. IMO, given clarity of code and ease of data-binding  I would still opt for the idiomatic way using your `normalRoutine`.

Comment: Yes, this is a little broad question. I am trying to get more guidences or solutions on this performance issue. Thanks for your comment.